# RecyclerView Update Single Item's Child

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-recyclerview

[image]

My `Recyclerview` list is as in the picture.

I want to update the child (example: just the 'Like' part) of a single item in my list. I did some research on the subject. I can update the whole item. However, what I need is to update one child of the item. I need code snippet on this. I'm new here, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a class named **User** and you are passing an ArrayList(that contains different User objects) to the RecyclerView Adapter.

```
public class User
{
    ....
    private String name;
    private int age;
    //Getters, setters, etc ....
}
```

So for updating just the **age**, simply update that object present at that specific position in the list and then just refresh the RecyclerView.

```
....
users.get(position).setAge(xyz);
userAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
....
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked for me :)